# importing and exporting tracking

Tags: magento-1.9, importexport, shipment-tracking, ecommerce-tracking

I am currently looking for a Magento extension on importing and exporting tracking numbers. That being said I've come across many extension for this, and need help/recommendations on which one might suit me best? (this is for large bulk tracking import and exports) p.s i am currently using Magento 1.9